# Facebook Graph API - cannot block users via app (Service temporarily unavailable)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a component which blocks facebook users from pages via Graph API. I'm using the ['blocked' edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/blocked/) of the respective page. For example, to block a user via cURL:

`curl -si -X POST -d "asid=%5B[appScopedUserId]%5D" -d "access_token=[pageAccessToken]" "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/[pageId]/blocked"`

This works fine, as long as I receive the access token via Graph API Explorer. As soon as I use my own app to receive the page access token, it stops working. I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#2) Service temporarily unavailable","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":2,"fbtrace_id":"CtEMxKXHoZK"}}
```

Issuing a DELETE request on this edge to un-block a user doesn't work neither - I get a `{"success":true}` answer, but the user is still in the list (wtf?).
Oddly enough, I can send GET requests to this edge and receive the list of currently blocked users with no problem.

Now as my problem only exists when I use the page access token received through my app, I suspect this is a permission problem. But when I use the [access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) on the token in use, it lists "manage_pages" among the scopes.

This is driving me nuts. The error message is not helpful at all (it already said 'temporarily unavailable' yesterday), and I've run out of ideas what could be the issue. Thanks a lot in advance if someone can help me out here!

Comment: And the app-scoped user id you are using is associated with _your_ app as well?

Comment: @CBroe nope, it was not, I had the IDs hard-wired for testing. Argh .. Please feel free to answer the question. Thank you so very much mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app-scoped user id used in your call must belong to the app that the access token is from.